# Trying to figure out why my data is being insert even with the trigger without ouputting the DBMS outputs

Tags: sql, oracle11g, triggers

I am trying to see if the item that is being inserted is a game or not if its a game Im suppose to get a output saying it is a game otherwise if it isn't a game Im suppose to get a print out saying it is not a game but no matter what I do it always inserts without evening outputting anything even where there suppose to be results

```
create or replace
TRIGGER AgeItem
BEFORE INSERT ON orderItem
for each row
DECLARE
customerAge int;
gameAge int;
pid int;
gid int;
a varchar(255);
CURSOR life is 
      SELECT games.gameid FROM games;
BEGIN
OPEN life;
LOOP
FETCH life into gid;
EXIT WHEN life%notfound;
END LOOP;
CLOSE life;


SELECT DISTINCT product.productid into pid
FROM orderitem, product
WHERE product.productid = :new.productorderid;

exception when no_data_found then  a:= 'Not a Game';

if pid = gid then
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Is a game'); 
else
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(a); 
end IF ;
End;
```

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Add`SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` in the session where you execute `Insert` . Issue a `Commit` or `Rollback` , the message should appear.